# Run 2 asynchronous functions synchronously with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have two functions that take arguments and are async:

```
updateCartNote(cartNote);
```

And

```
updateCartAttributes(attributeToUpdate);
```

Both of these use AJAX to update a shopping cart, the issue is, is that I have to run them synchronously. I've tried multiple ways with `when` and `then` and using callbacks, and nothing seems to work. My latest attempt is with the following:

```
function keepCartNoteAndDate(cartNote, deliveryDate){
  console.log("keepCartNoteAndDate");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/cart/update.js',
    data: 'note=' + cartNote,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "js",
    complete: function() {
      updateCartAttributes({delivery_date: deliveryDate});
    },
  });
}
```

I extracted the AJAX function for updating `CartNote` and then just put the `updateCartAttributes` in the `complete` section. But no luck.

Where did I go astray?

Comment: this looks fine, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: `I have to run them synchronously` <= no you don't or you are using the wrong terminology. What are you trying to accomplish? One run function only after the other has completed? Something else? What is "not working" (paraphrasing "nothing seems to work")